# Where can I find this Space Shuttle Memo?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, reference-request

T. J. Fill, “PEG Prediction Corrections,” Shuttle Memo 10E-80-11, The Charles Stark Draper Laboratory, Inc., Cambridge, MA, March 1980.

And this isn't a request to violate copyright, if that's an issue.  I would think it would be accessible via NTRS or some other online library like that.  I can't see anywhere that I could pay CSDL to obtain access to it.  I don't know of any library where these CSDL memos would be accessible.

Comment: Have you just tried using the contact form on the Draper lab website? Or contacting the author?  His contact info is on papers I've found that cite that memo.

Comment: Nope, didn't even think of that, working on that now...

Comment: You may try the library of Congress, there is an internet access to the books list.